# Mongoose - check if database exists

Tags: reactjs, mongoose, mongoose-schema

A [Mongoose connection](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html) to a named Atlas database returns no error if the database does not exist. Connections are always successful as long as the URI and credentials are valid.

**Is it possible to return an error if the specified database does not exist?**

I'm modeling my app on [Jelo's MERN write-up](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/full-stack-mongodb-react-node-js-express-js-in-one-simple-app-6cc8ed6de274).

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Data = require("./data");

const API_PORT = 3001;
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

// Atlas database
const uri = "mongodb+srv://USERNAME:PASSWORD@CLUSTER-xdmza.mongodb.net/"
const dbName = "fakedatabase"

const options = {
autoReconnect: true,
useNewUrlParser: true,
dbName: dbName
}

// Connect backend app to MongoDB with options
mongoose.connect(uri, options);
let db = mongoose.connection;

// connection event handlers
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "MongoDB connection error:"));
db.on("connected", console.error.bind(console, "MongoDB database: " + dbName));
db.on("disconnected", console.error.bind(console, "MongoDB database: " + dbName));
```

The code above returns:

```
MongoDB connected: fakedatabase
```

I'd like to trigger the "error" event handler and log the corresponding message.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is possible to trigger the error event handler but you can check if database exists using [listDatabases](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/listDatabases/) function from Mongo. Using Mongoose this can be done like this:

```
db.once("open", () => {
    new mongoose.mongo.Admin(db).listDatabases((err, res) => {
         //Array of databases is in res.databases   
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Ultimately, I used the Stitch SDK rather than use Mongoose. It was much easier. The [Create a Stitch App](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/procedures/create-stitch-app/) docs are really good.